# Amazon SNS for APNS

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon SNS in my restful web service to send push notification to my device. In the logs, I get success message and also the message id. The only problem(major one) is that most of the times I don't get the notification on the device. Notifications are received quite rarely and this behavior is erratic.
Looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

You get success message and message id because your message was published to the topic. It has nothing to do with the delivery status of those messages, i.e whether it was actually delivered to subscriber endpoints or not.

Since you mentioned that notifications are received intermittently, you should check [CloudWatch's](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/MonitorSNSwithCloudWatch.html) `NumberOfNotificationsDelivered` and `NumberOfNotificationsFailed` metrics which can verify the delivered/failed status of the messages.